# r street type removing pattern match

Tags: r, substring

I need to remove the street type (St, Blvd, Rd, etc) from a series of addresses as the clean up step before a data match. I'm using the code below, but for some addresses the result is missing part of the street I want to keep.

```
library(tidyverse)
c("9123 GLENOAKS BLVD","123 E AVENUE K6 STE B","123 CAMP PLENTY RD","900 E VICTORIA ST","460 SAN FERNANDO RD","176 S SANTA FE AVE STE 9") %>% 
sub("AVE.*$|ST.*$| BLVD.*$| RD.*$| PL.*$| 3RD.*$| APT.*$| DR.*$", "", .) 

[1] "9123 GLENOAKS"    "123 E "           "123 CAMP"         "900 E VICTORIA "  "460 SAN FERNANDO" "176 S SANTA FE "
```

Below is the expected output

```
[1] "9123 GLENOAKS"    "123 E AVENUE K6 "           "123 CAMP PLENTY"         "900 E VICTORIA "  "460 SAN FERNANDO" "176 S SANTA FE "
```

Comment: `.` is a regex character meaning "any character". So when you use `AVE.` as your regex it means `AVE` followed by any character. You can use an escape character to fix this with something like `AVE\\.`. (Double escaping in necessary in R, but not in other regex programs which would need `AVE\.`)

Comment: Is that `ST` always `ST` or `STE`? Try `sub("(.*?)(?:\\s+(?:AVE|STE?|BLVD|RD|PL|3RD|APT|DR)\\b).*$", "\\1", .)`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew this seems to work, can you put it in an answer so that I can mark it as such? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
sub("(.*?)\\s+(?:AVE|STE?|BLVD|RD|PL|3RD|APT|DR)\\b.*", "\\1", .)
```

**Details**

- `(.*?)` - Group 1 (this group will hold the value referenced to with `\1` from the replacement pattern): any 0 or more chars as few as possible
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `(?:AVE|STE?|BLVD|RD|PL|3RD|APT|DR)` - a list of the string alternatives: `AVE`, `ST` or `STE`, `BLVD`, `RD`, `PL`, `3RD`, `APT`  or `DR`
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `.*` - the rest of the input.